# Get #ERROR! and #NAME? in cell sheet when I use the .setFormula () in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to include a function in cells in a column, based on the value of the cell in the same row in the next column and the value in a fixed cell.

I have created my code in GAS that you can see here:

```
function enviar_datos_formulario_anadir_mascota_a_bd_fichas() {

  var libro = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var hojaOrigen = libro.getSheetByName("Añadir ficha");
  var hojaDestino = libro.getSheetByName("BD Fichas");

  var row = hojaDestino.getLastRow() + 1;

  var fechaHoy = hojaDestino.getRange("H6").setFormula("=TODAY()");
  var fechaNacimiento = hojaDestino.getRange(row, 9); 
  var edad = hojaDestino.getRange(row, 8);

 edad.setFormula('=IF(ISBLANK(\'fechaNacimiento\')=FALSE;DATEDIF(\'fechaNacimiento\';\'fechaHoy\';"Y");"")');

}
```

I have also tried with:

`edad.setFormula('=IF(ISBLANK('+fechaNacimiento+')=FALSE;DATEDIF('+fechaNacimiento+';'+fechaHoy+';"Y");"")');`

And also with:

`edad.setFormula('=IF(ISBLANK(\"fechaNacimiento\")=FALSE;DATEDIF(\"fechaNacimiento\";\"fechaHoy\";"Y");"")');`

For whatever reason, I can't get it to work. It throws me the #ERROR! or #NAME?  notice.
I attach screenshots below:

[image: error setformula]

[image: name error setformula]

Could someone tell me what the problem really is?

Thank you in advance

Comment: This is more of a formula issue rather than a google scripts issue so I modified your tags to include users that are more likely to know formulas

Comment: This is not a problem of formula.

The formula placed directly in the cell works correctly. I have this problem only with google apps script and setformula ()    @Cooper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following `Apps Script` function to solve your problem, just replace the `Sheet name` with your version then should be working, one the main problem of your existing code is did not obtain `A1notation` and you do not need to perform `escape` in the formula if you want to refer to other `range` and variable `hojaOrigen`  was not used at all:

```
function UntitledMacro3() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheetD = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Dockets');
  var sheetU = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('USERNAMES');

  var row = sheetU.getLastRow() + 1;

  var fechaHoyrange = sheetU.getRange("H6");
  fechaHoyrange.setFormula("=TODAY()");
  var fechaHoy = fechaHoyrange.getA1Notation();
  var fechaNacimiento = sheetU.getRange(row, 9).getA1Notation(); 

  var edad = sheetU.getRange(row, 8);
  edad.setFormula('=IF(ISBLANK('+fechaNacimiento+')=FALSE,DATEDIF('+fechaNacimiento+','+fechaHoy+',"Y"),"")');
 
};
```

[image]

Comment: This worked perfect for me and solved the problem completely. I had to do some modification because this data is inside a larger function and because my spreadsheet works with ";" instead of ",", but the rest of the code worked perfectly.
Thank you very much for your help!! I have learned something new. :)  @Kin Siang

Comment: Welcome,  i also learn something new during by trying to solve this issue :)